# Expect script not prompting for sftp

Tags: bash, sftp, expect

i wonder what may be wrong here

I do an sftp expect script which will prompt me for password, but never seems to send the password in. Or if it does send it encrypted, we still do not get to the sftp prompt. Any ideas?

```
cd /proj/eiffel004_config_fem107/slaves/RHEL6.4_GE_3/workspace/Remote_Agent_Test/
/usr/bin/expect << 'EOF' 
set timeout -1
spawn sftp root@server
expect { 
            "*assword: " 
       }
send "thePassword \r"
expect { 
            "sftp>  " 
       }
send "put filename \r"
expect { 
            "100" 
       }
send "exit \r"       
EOF
```

Output is

```
+ cd /proj/eiffel004_config_fem107/slaves/RHEL6.4_GE_3/workspace/Remote_Agent_Test/
+ /usr/bin/expect
spawn sftp root@server
Connecting to server...
Warning: Permanently added 'server,102.44.79.32' (RSA) to the list of known 
hosts.

root@server's password:
```

Comment: Use `/usr/bin/expect -d` to see why the pattern is not matching.

Comment: take a look at [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Comment: @pynexj, just suggesting a different tool is not going to help resolve this problem. I wish you could be more judicious with your promotion.